# Can I use Microsoft Office PartnerCenter SDK for customer admin level instead of CSP level?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, powershell, office365

Using [Microsoft PartnerCenter SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/), I m trying to login to a Customer Admin level through my application. Is that possible ?

I have already used the same SDK for CSP level with success in another application, allowing the CSP to add customer in their [PartnerCenter](https://partner.microsoft.com/en-GB/).

Suppose this CSP has created a customer, what I want in this application now is to login in that customer admin account using its username and password and perform operations (like create a new user or assign some licenses to some user). By the way, These operations are perform-able on [Admin Portal](https://portal.office.com/Adminportal/).

Remember, I only have credentials for the admin account of a single customer of that CSP.

So, does this SDK allow me to login using credentials of a cloud reseller instead of a CSP or their are some other APIs for admin operations ?

EDIT:
I dont want to register an app in Azure AD,
means i just want to use my login credentials (username, password).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED: I used PowerShell commands in my code to perform these actions.